# How to send output with multiple values from extjs to Yii controller action

Tags: extjs, yii, output

I am working in extjs+yii. My server side is in yii framework and client side is in extjs. Now I want to pass extjs's submit buttons output to yii action. I am creating multiple choice question paper of 20 questions in extjs whose actual questions will come from server side action which is written in Yii framewok. Up to this, it is working correctly.

Now after solving all questions by marking its respective radio buttons as an answer, on the click of submit button I want to send these 20 questions `userId`, `questionId` and selected radio buttons option to yii controller action. I had written submit button action as:

```
     check:function()
            {
        console.log("Inside check function.");
        //creating objects in javascript
          var obj=new Object();
          for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)
          {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i); 
                var radio = "";  
                for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    if (inputs[j].checked) {
                        name = inputs[j].name;
                        value  = inputs[j].value;
                        //obj[i].name1=name;
                        obj[i]={'questionId':name,'option':value};
                        console.log("questionId="+name +" value="+ value);
                        console.log("object name="+ obj[i].questionNo+" Object value="+obj[i].option);
                    }
                }
          }
    }
});
```

So I am getting `questionId` and `optionValue` of all questions on submit button click. Now I want to send all the `questionid` and `optionValue` data to yii action. So how to send it to extjs action?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your data to an action in a controller with AJAX
for example : site/savequestions

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:"site/savequestions",
        method: "POST",
        params: {'qid': name, 'aid':value},
        success: function(){
            console.log("ok");
        },
        failure: function(response, opts){
            console.log("failed");
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
```

and then in the controller `SiteController` you would have

```
public function actionSavequestion()
{
    $questionId = Yii::app()->request->getParam('qid');
    $anserId = Yii::app()->request->getParam('aid');
    //... do stuff here

    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    exit()
}
```