# How to send extjs data to yii controller action

Tags: extjs, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send output with multiple values from extjs to Yii controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277666/how-to-send-output-with-multiple-values-from-extjs-to-yii-controller-action)

I am working in extjs and Yii framework. I had designed multiple choice question paper in extjs. Yii controller function is attached with extjs store to supply these questions from database.

Now i want to save user's selected answer `optionId` into database. i.e. from extjs i want to send papers all user solved questions `questionId` with user's selected `optionId` to Yii controller action. I had written code on submit button event as:

```
    check:function()
    {
        console.log("Inside check function.");
        //creating objects in javascript
          var obj=new Object();
          for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)
          {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i); 
                var radio = "";  
                for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    if (inputs[j].checked) {
                        name = inputs[j].name;
                        value  = inputs[j].value;
                        //obj[i].name1=name;
                        obj[i]={'questionId':name,'option':value};
                        console.log("questionId="+name +" value="+ value);
                        console.log("object name="+ obj[i].questionNo+" Object value="+obj[i].option);
                    }// End of if statment
                }// End of inner for loop
          }//End of outer for loop
    }// End of check function
});//End of Controller
```

So what modifications i need to do in order to send required data to yii controller action. I really need help...

Comment: Are you asking for the javascript or the PHP or both?

Comment: I am asking for php sir...

Answer (score 1):

You should post your data to an action in a controller with AJAX
for example : site/savequestions

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:"site/savequestions",
        method: "POST",
        params: {'qid': name, 'aid':value},
        success: function(){
            console.log("ok");
        },
        failure: function(response, opts){
            console.log("failed");
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
```

and then in the controller `SiteController` you would have

```
public function actionSavequestion()
{
    $questionId = Yii::app()->request->getParam('qid');
    $anserId = Yii::app()->request->getParam('aid');
    //... do stuff here

    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    exit()
}
```